# What is the name of this insect?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

[image]

This insect was found in my garden in India on the evening of August 07, 2019. It's rainy season here.

Comment: it's a leafhopper. a lot of them have horns. You are supposed to state the location of your garden, if it's in america/india/UK/south africa.  https://www.google.com/search?q=horned+leafhopper&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkn4yml_HjAhXtAmMBHe5NBDAQ_AUIECgB&biw=1972&bih=1009

Comment: Not a leafhopper but a treehopper (same order, suborder and infraorder, different family); if another is seen a side view will help (the pronotum of all treehoppers is of high value in identification, but we do need that side view to go further -- which will be done by someone else; I don't know the Indian fauna of the group).

Answer (score 3):

This is a [treehopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treehopper) (an insect in the family Membracidae).

As Arthur J Frost mentioned in his [comment](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/86015/what-is-the-name-of-this-insect#comment153486_86015) above, it will be difficult to ID this specimen more specifically given the angle, lack of further info, and my personal lack of knowledge of Indian fauna.

However, you can view an at-least similar looking species by viewing *Oxyrachis tarandus*, which is found in India (see [here](https://indiabiodiversity.org/observation/show/368842) and [Sharma & Pati (2011)](http://idosi.org/wasj/wasj14%289%2911/13.pdf)<sup>1</sup>).

You can find photos of *O. tarandus* [here](http://www.natureloveyou.sg/Minibeast-Hopper/Oxyrachis%20tarandus/Main.html), with one copied below for reference.

[image]

<sup>© [www.NatureLoveYou.sg](http://www.natureloveyou.sg/Minibeast-Hopper/Oxyrachis%20tarandus/DSC01006%20(11).JPG)</sup>

---

<sup>1. Sharma, A. and Pati, P.K., 2011. First report of Withania somnifera (L.) Dunal, as a new host of cowbug (Oxyrachis tarandus, Fab.) in plains of Punjab, northern India. World Applied Sciences Journal, 14(9), pp.1344-1346.</sup>